# io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Dog is not part of the schema for this Realm

Tags: android, realm

I create a Realm model and tried to save the value in the realm. But Realm throws

> "RealmModelClassName" is not part of the schema for this Realm

I tried various method which is suggested in stackoverflow. But nothing solves the problem.

I did clean/rebuild repeatedly for resolving the issue.

I faced the above error whenever I tried to save the

```
realm.beginTransaction()
        val managedDog = realm.copyToRealm(dog);
        realm.commitTransaction()
```

App Level Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gofrugal.databaseproject"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    android {
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility 1.8
            targetCompatibility 1.8
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Project Level Gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.8.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: your class extends RealmObject?

Comment: @pavel-poley I tried two methods. One is extending RealmObject. And another method is implementing RealmModel with RealmClass annotation

Comment: probably something with kotlin plugins, try to browse this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887303/object-is-not-part-of-the-schema-for-this-realm

Comment: do you use realm modules ? `@RealmModule(classes = {...})`

Comment: also check this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54558333/how-to-fix-object-is-not-part-of-the-schema-for-this-realm