# How to fix "Object is not part of the schema for this Realm"

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm trying to set up an application that uses the `Realm` database but I can't seem to make it work. I've also disabled `Instant Run` but that didn't solve the problem either.

Here are my code files:

**App level build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' // <-- these two were the problem
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'            // <--
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

**Project level build.gradle**

```
dependencies{
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.8.0'
}
```

**One of my model classes**

```
public class ClothingItem extends RealmObject{
    private String mItemName;
    private RealmList<String> mItemTags;
    ....
```

**Application class where I initialize Realm**

```
public void onCreate(){
    super.oncreate();
    Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .name("MyOnlineWardrobe.realm")
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
}
```

Comment: when I created the project I wanted to use kotlin but ended up not using it. I deleted the 2 kotlin plugins and that solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // <---
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```